# VB.Net: Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm creating an application that will be able to tell me who is logged onto what PC, in the manufacturing center, where I work.

I'm using psexec's psloggedon cmd process to get me the information for me and a VB.net windows application to show me the information.

I begin by first querying a databse for all the PC's we currently have active and dumping the data into a datagridview object. (Shown below)

```
Private Sub Button(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btngetPC.Click  

    'GET AREAS FROM DATABASE
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim db As String = "QUERY STRING GOES HERE"

    'CONNECT TO DATABASE
    Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(db, MySQLConnection)
        da.Fill(ds, "MACHINE_NAME")
    End Using
    With datagridView1
        .DataSource = ds.Tables("MACHINE_NAME")
    End With

    'ADD COLUMN TO DATAGRIDVIEW
    datagridView1.Columns.Add("LOGGED_IN", "LOGGED_IN")
    MySQLConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

Once I have my datagridview object filled out with all my active PC's, I can then use the machine names to run the psloggedon cmd to get who is logged in. I do so by using:

```
Private Sub execute(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntExecuteCmd.Click

    'COUNT ENTRIES
    Dim RowCount As Integer = datagridView1.RowCount
    ''EXECUTE CMD
    For i = 0 To RowCount - 2
        'PERFORM PSLOGGEDON ROUTINE
        Dim Proc1 As New Process
        Proc1.StartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("psloggedon")
        Proc1.StartInfo.Arguments = "-l \\" & datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & ""
        Proc1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Proc1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Proc1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Proc1.Start()

        If Not Proc1.WaitForExit(300) Then
            Proc1.Kill()
        End If

        'INSERT RESULTS INTO LOGGEN_IN COLUMN
        Dim msg As String = Proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        Dim idx As Integer = msg.LastIndexOf("\"c)
        Dim user As String = msg.Substring(idx + 1)
        Dim final As String = UCase(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(user, "^ELP.*$", ""))
        datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = final
    Next
End Sub
```

Finally, here is my question:
To get the employee names I must use regex becuase the raw format is unacceptable.

raw format:
"Connecting to Registry of \ELPSC171698...

Users logged on locally:
          ECHOSTAR\Jane.Doe"

format after applying:

```
'INSERT RESULTS INTO LOGGEN_IN COLUMN  

        Dim msg As String = Proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        Dim idx As Integer = msg.LastIndexOf("\"c)
        Dim user As String = msg.Substring(idx + 1)
        Dim final As String = UCase(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(user, "^ELP.*$", ""))
        datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = final
```

"PAULA.RODRIGUEZ"

Looks good, right? However, when the raw format has more than one associate, like so:

"Connecting to Registry of \ELPSC173068...

Users logged on locally:
          ECHOSTAR\John.Doe
          ECHOSTAR\Ben.Doe"

the code I have written will get me the last person in this list. In this case, I will get JOHN.DOE when I need to get BEN.DOE.

Now the question: How can I change this code:

```
'INSERT RESULTS INTO LOGGEN_IN COLUMN  

        Dim msg As String = Proc1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
        Dim idx As Integer = msg.LastIndexOf("\"c)
        Dim user As String = msg.Substring(idx + 1)
        Dim final As String = UCase(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(user, "^ELP.*$", ""))
        datagridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = final
```

To get me the first person, "JOHN.DOE" from here:

"Connecting to Registry of \ELPSC173068...

Users logged on locally:
          ECHOSTAR\John.Doe
          ECHOSTAR\Ben.Doe"

I hope my question was clear and well constructed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use more specific regex and a capture group to get multiple items.

```
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches("Users logged on locally: ECHOSTAR\John.Doe ECHOSTAR\Ben.Doe", "[\t ]+[a-z_0-9]+\\(?<n>[a-z_\.0-9]+)(([\t ])|($))", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline)
    For Each m As Match In mc
        Dim name As String = m.Groups("n").value
    Next
```

if you just want the first one then...

```
If mc.Count >= 1 Then
    Dim name As String = mc(0).Groups("n").Value
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Dim idx As Integer = msg.LastIndexOf("\"c)
```

to

```
Dim idx As Integer = msg.IndexOf("\"c)
```

Alternatively consider this:

Assuming you've validated the string first.

```
Dim user As String = msg.Split({"\"c, " "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1) _
                     .Replace("."c, " "c).ToUpper
```

To leave the decimal in just remove `.Replace("."c, " "c)`